# SqlDataReader dbnull values

Tags: c#-4.0, sqldatareader

I have a question about SqlDataReader:

Is there some way to modificated the values in SqlDataReader? For example:

```
while (sdr.Read())
{
     double PRICE = double.Parse(sdr["PRICE"].ToString());
     if (PRICE == null) PRICE = Single.MinValue;
     .....
}
```

I would like that for each null value in my DataReader, assigned Single.MinValue to use after this modifications in another process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can modify SqlDataReader. 
Source: [MSDN - Contrasting the ADO.NET DataReader and DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188717.aspx)

> The DataReader has a defined set of operations that revolve around its
>   connected, forward-only, read-only nature.

You may use [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to achieve what you want.